# How can I use a ruby program to save an array of hashes to a csv file?

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, methods, io

I have an array of hashes that contain sales data in a ruby program and would like to write code that would save this data to a csv file that I can later access or update. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Do you have a reason for wanting to use CSV format (e.g., to read it into a spreadsheet), or do you just want to save the contents of the array so you can retrieve it later for further processing with Ruby? If the later, consider using [Marshall](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html) instead.  Marshall is an easy way to take a snapshot of a Ruby object which you can optionally save to a file.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for you comment. I need to save the contents of the array so I can retrieve it later for further processing. I will need to be able to query the array in the csv for sales data within certain date ranges

Comment: If you are certain you want to save the data in CSV format, one answer points you to the CSV class. CSV is normally used to transfer between programs that do not share a more convenient format.  If you are not wedded to CSV, you may wish to edit your question to provide more information about what you want to do.  For example, if you plan to periodically save sales data to separate files, and then read those files for processing, consider saving the data in a database instead (e.g., [SQLite](http://viewsourcecode.org/why/hacking/aQuickGuideToSQLite.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ruby [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html) builtin class for serialization.

```
# load array from array.bin or initialize new array
array = if File.exists?('array.bin')
           File.open('array.bin') do|file|
             Marshal.load(file)
           end
         else
           []
         end

# see what's in array
puts array.inspect

# modify array
array << ["test"]

# save into array.bin file
File.open('array.bin','w') do|file|
  Marshal.dump(array, file)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @retro. would it be possible to use the .csv extension in this case? I need to save it to a csv file so that I can later query the information by date range.

Comment: No, you need to write your own transformation from ruby array to CSV. This will serialize your array into binary file. After loading it again, you'll get same array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider using class CSV from Ruby standard library.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html